# saying boruch shem out loud on Yom Kippur but not immediately after?

Tags: yom-kippur, shema, loud-quiet

The entire Yom Kippur we say the "boruch shem" after "shema" out loud, contrary to the normal whispered tone, because we are compared to angels on this day. The question is, when Yom Kippur first starts we are more in touch with physicality, for example eating and normal shoes etc., and in the first prayer we say it out loud; but, yet, in ma'ariv after Yom Kippur we've fasted for 25 hours and are so out of touch with the world, but then we don't say it out loud. Wouldn't it make more sense to say it out loud then rather than when Yom Kippur first starts?

Comment: Why are you still fasting on the day after Yom Kippur?

Comment: @DoubleAA, you break your fast before _maariv_? Most people don't.

Comment: Short answer: you say it when Yom Kippur starts since it's already Yom Kippur, and you don't say it after Yom Kippur ends because it's not Yom Kippur anymore. There's a set way to pray, and while hopefully we're in the appropriate mindset, we have to follow the guidelines regardless of how 'spiritual' we feel at any given moment. For the same reason, even if I felt particularly spiritual on a random day in mid-May for example, I still wouldn't be allowed to say that line out loud.

Comment: @msh210 Sometimes I do, sometimes I don't. I'm not aware of a reason to prefer one way or the other. Perhaps most people you know just aren't so hungry yet and are already in Shul.

Comment: As soon as Yom Kippur is over, it is over. Our prayers go back to weekday ones even though we are still connected (we hope) to the sentiment of Y"K http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30713/vehu-rachum-and-selach-lanu-for-maariv-after-yom-kippur

Comment: As soon as Yom Kippur is over we start thinking about food.  I don't know about your shul, but everywhere I have been, it is the fastest Maariv of the year!

Comment: In mine we usually recite Kiddush Levana afterwards if we can see the moon.

Comment: "...we've fasted for 25 hours and are so out of touch with the world" - I don't understand your intent, here. As stated, above, most people are VERY much IN touch with the world as soon as Yom Kippur is done. They can't wait for food. "Crazy" or "delirious"? That's, perhaps, another story. But, even delirious people are in touch with the world :-)

Comment: @wizzardmr42 I saw a source that said basically the same thing (minus the fast Maariv part). The idea is that we are what we strive to be.